# Failed to import project from GtiHub, No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, stripe-payments

I am importing Card Scanner project from [here](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source) but when I import the project it gives error no 2:

> No such file or dirctory

on this line in build.gradle:

```
"git describe --match=*[0-9]*.[0-9]*.*[0-9] --tags --dirty --always".execute().text.trim()
```

I am not getting the exact meaning if this apart from the line saying no such file or directory and that too is, I don't know what!

Comment: Question is not clear enough. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit: you checked out the project and ran "gradle". Did you follow the steps in the readme (clone, submodule, properties)? The command you have indicated seems to be in [this gradle file](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source/blob/master/card.io/build.gradle)

Comment: I just cannot import the project the project. It is still saying "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio (Gradle): Check out this blog post: http://blog.android-develop.com/2014/09/automatic-versioning-and-increment.html

Here's the implementation from the blog:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
...
    // Fetch the version according to git latest tag and "how far are we from last tag"
    def longVersionName = "git -C ${rootDir} describe --tags --long".execute().text.trim()
    def (fullVersionTag, versionBuild, gitSha) = longVersionName.tokenize('-')
    def(versionMajor, versionMinor, versionPatch) = fullVersionTag.tokenize('.')

    // Set the version name
    versionName "$versionMajor.$versionMinor.$versionPatch($versionBuild)"

    // Turn the version name into a version code
    versionCode versionMajor.toInteger() * 100000 +
            versionMinor.toInteger() * 10000 +
            versionPatch.toInteger() * 1000 +
            versionBuild.toInteger()

    // Friendly print the version output to the Gradle console
    printf("\n--------" + "VERSION DATA--------" + "\n" + "- CODE: " + versionCode + "\n" + 
           "- NAME: " + versionName + "\n----------------------------\n")
...
}
```